# Warning findCorrelation in R carret package "Combination row and column is above the cut-off" and not getting and return values

Tags: r, correlation, pattern-recognition, r-caret

I am currently trying to filter variables [data](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv) based on their correlation
with the carret package from R in RStudio on my Mac.

So far I can calculate and print the correlation of the data set. However, once I am applying the findCorrelation method I am not getting any data returned. I only get the following warning:

"  Combination row  and column  is above the cut-off, value = Flagging column"

```
library(caret)
preProcessAttributeClass <- function (data.convert) {
classe <- data.convert$classe
data.convert <- as.data.frame(sapply(data.convert,as.numeric))
data.convert$X.1 <- NULL
data.convert$X <- NULL
data.convert$user_name <- NULL
data.convert$raw_timestamp_part_1 <- NULL
data.convert$raw_timestamp_part_2 <- NULL
data.convert$cvtd_timestamp <- NULL
data.convert$new_window <- NULL
data.convert$num_window <- NULL
data.convert
}

data.train <- read.csv(file="training.csv",na.strings=c("NA",""))
data.train <- preProcessAttributeClass(data.train)
descrCor <- (cor(na.omit(data.train),use="complete.obs"))
highlyCorDescr <- findCorrelation(na.omit(descrCor), cutoff = .9,    verbose=TRUE,names=FALSE)
```

Any ideas what could be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Have you tried lowering your cutoff? It looks like none of your combinations have a correlation >= 0.9.

Comment: yes I tried that  even with 0.1 and it  doesn't make a difference. also I can see the data in descrCor, but there are some NA which are not removed by na.omit. could this be the cause?

Comment: can you post a minimal sample of your data? If na.omit isn't working it makes me think they R isn't recognizing some of your NA's as actually missing, but impossible to tell without a reproducible example

Comment: Completely missed the link to your data but it looks like the creator of caret answered your question so I think you should be good!

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is your correlation matrix:

```
> class(na.omit(descrCor))
[1] "matrix"
> dim(na.omit(descrCor))
[1]   0 153
```

These data have columns with a lot of missing data:

```
> pct_na <- unlist(lapply(data.train, function(x) mean(is.na(x))))
> summary(pct_na)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.9793  0.6401  0.9793  0.9793
```

I'll punt on whether columns with ~95% missing are useful but they are preventing you from getting a useful correlation matrix. I suggest doing the correlation filter with fewer columns:

```
> sum(pct_na > .1)
[1] 100
> keepers <- data.train[,names(which(pct_na <= .1))]
> descrCor <- cor(keepers ,use="complete.obs")
```

Most of the remaining columns have either no correlations or very high ones:

```
> summary(descrCor[upper.tri(descrCor)])
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-0.992000 -0.108800  0.001911  0.001667  0.088680  0.980900
```

Now do the filter:

```
> highlyCorDescr <- findCorrelation(descrCor, cutoff = .9,    verbose=TRUE,names=FALSE)
Compare row 10  and column  1 with corr  0.992 
  Means:  0.266 vs 0.164 so flagging column 10 
Compare row 1  and column  9 with corr  0.925 
  Means:  0.247 vs 0.161 so flagging column 1 
Compare row 9  and column  4 with corr  0.928 
  Means:  0.229 vs 0.158 so flagging column 9 
Compare row 8  and column  2 with corr  0.966 
  Means:  0.24 vs 0.154 so flagging column 8 
Compare row 19  and column  18 with corr  0.918 
  Means:  0.089 vs 0.155 so flagging column 18 
Compare row 46  and column  31 with corr  0.914 
  Means:  0.099 vs 0.158 so flagging column 31 
Compare row 46  and column  33 with corr  0.933 
  Means:  0.081 vs 0.161 so flagging column 33 
All correlations <= 0.9 
> keep_these <- names(data.train)[!(names(data.train) %in% colnames(descrCor)[highlyCorDescr])]
> data.train.subset <- data.train[, keep_these]
```